# Trace the Repository 's Get method with SQLPROFILER

Tags: c#, visual-studio, repository-pattern, sql-server-profiler

I have a performance issue caused by a latency in return from  the Repository 's Get method .

```
  var res = Data.TicketRepository.GetSingle(filterExpression, includeNavigations);
```

So i configured a trace on my database to view the sql statement generated by that linq-to-sql function.
However after the debugger finish with that method i don't get any trace  in the profiler.

what m i doing wrong ?

Is it possible for the profiler to track the execution that have been triggred outside of SSMS ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for the profiler to track the execution that have been triggred outside of SSMS ?

Yes.  You're doing something wrong.  Profiler can track activity from every session.

If you discover your sessions session_id by running `select @@spid`, you can filter that in Profiler.

[image]

Comment: i have selected the spid but the issue remains no trace !

Comment: Are you connected to the correct SQL Instance with sufficient permissions?

Comment: yes i do actually , i can get trace for other code execution from the session of visual studio but not for that

Comment: the repository code is executed from another project using a dll

Comment: Profiler can see all sessions, regardless of which project makes the connection.